# Graphics G in another method

Tags: java, swing, java-canvas

I have a canvas and I want to draw a rectangle based on a JButton click.

So in other words

```
private void jb_drawActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // draw a rectangle method
}
```

Basically, how do I encorporate the pain(Graphics g) thingamagic in that method? or should I make the rectangle an object and call a "render" method from that object? If so, can someone link a tut?

```
private void jb_drawActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    myrectange.render(x,y); // ????
}
```

Comment: Never try to call `paint(Graphics g)` yourself, always delegate this to a call to `repaint`. 1) Call `repaint()` in your `jb_drawActionPerformed` method. 2) Override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and in that method paint your rectangle. The first call will eventually trigger the second one. Btw, you should always override `paintComponent` and never override `paint(Graphics g)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General Comments and Recommendations

- One way: Draw in a BufferedImage getting your Graphics object from the BufferedImage, and then draw the BufferedImage in the JComponent's (JPanel's?) paintComponent method.
- If you do it this way, you will use the Graphics object directly obtained from the BufferedImage to do your drawing.
- Don't forget to dispose of this Graphics object when done with it.
- The actual drawing though is done in the JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method (see below).
- Another way: change a class field, and have the JPanel's paintComponent method use that field when painting. For instance, if you want to paint multiple Rectangles, create an `ArrayList<Rectangle>` add to it in your ActionListener, call `repaint()` and have the `paintComponent(...)` method iterate through the List, drawing rectangles held by it.
- Note that the `paintComponent(...)` method is never called directly but rather you suggest to the JVM that it call it by calling `repaint()`.
- Never dispose of a Graphics object that was given to you by the JVM, for instance the one passed into the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` parameter.

---

## Links

- Basic Tutorial: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- More advanced concepts: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)